# Unable to change audio source in NDK oboe LiveEffect sample code

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, oboe

I have downloaded the LiveEffect sample code based on the Oboe library from here: https://github.com/google/oboe/tree/master/samples/LiveEffect

And I have been able to build and run it on Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8.0

The program works as expected when choosing the AAudio library for NDK, but when choosing OpenSL ES library the audio always takes the default route. I want to make phone's built in mic the audio input while making the speaker of an external headphone with mic the output, but if a headphone is mic is connected, the audio input always defaults to the headset mic even though I select phone built in mic in the app's user interface. This same behaviour is seen in a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7 which only supports OpenSL ES.

I have not had any luck finding out how to change the audio input in Google's NDK based [audio-echo sample program](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/audio-echo) either, which also uses OpenSL Es. How do I specify the audio input source when using NDK audio based on OpenSL ES? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

The LiveEffect sample uses `setDeviceId` to specify which audio device to use. Here's [the docs](https://google.github.io/oboe/reference/classoboe_1_1_audio_stream_builder.html#af36ddcd00686a9e1de661bdac0685a8e) for `setDeviceId`:

> Note that when using OpenSL ES, this will be ignored and the created stream will have deviceId kUnspecified.

Unfortunately, OpenSL ES (being very old) does not support specifying an audio device. This means that the default audio device will always be used.

You may be able to achieve the behaviour you're looking for by using the Java APIs, specifically [`setPreferredDevice`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRouting#setPreferredDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo))

Comment: I tried using setPreferredDevice on an AudioRecord object I created in the NDK audio-echo sampe project (https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/audio-echo) which uses OpenSL ES and it didn't work. All the audio capture and playback happens from NDK so I suppose that is why sinplyt making an AudioRecord object in java and specifying preferred device didn't do anything, so I suppose it won't work here either

Comment: Is onAudioReady() function in FullDuplexStream.cpp the callback function in the Oboe sample? The older audio-echo project had a function call engine.delayEffect->process(...) inside it's callback function, and an exact number of audio samples, equal to the size of frame specified in java, used to be available in an array called liveAudio[]. What is the Oboe equivalent of this variable? Do you have any ideas about this? There is a numFrames available inside onAudioReady() but it keeps changing every time, while I have fixed the buffer size to be 192 from Java code

Comment: Please ask a new question for this.